# Should I keep downspout extenders installed during the winter?

Tags: roof, downspout

Should downspout extenders be kept installed during winter? For some reason, I think they facilitate ice formation to creep up the spout?

When I say downspout extenders, I mean [these](http://www.qcidirect.com/flex-a-spout---extends-to-55-in.html)

[image]

Comment: problem with those is that not all water drains out of the extenders which can then freeze

Comment: How about finding a square and hard plastic version, which would ensure water would drain and then it would be okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper drainage depends on a constant gradient. These flexible pipes don't provide that.

Those concentric corrugations and the flexibility that allows them to follow ground contour with a portion of the length dropping into a depression or having to go over an obstruction leaves a pool of water that freezes.

Elbows and rigid downspout stock to get the roof runoff out away from the foundation works best. There are fold-up metal/vinyl 48/60" extenders available that allow for flowerbed maintenance.

If you have a lot of winter precipitation as rain, or a lot of melt-water, you need to get the runoff out and away from the house foundation, which is the purpose of a proper downspout system. Thus, extending the outflow of the downspouts is needed year around to prevent this.